# What is the recommended way if injecting HTML with scripts into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml, script-tag

I have a requirement where I need to do unsafe HTML injection into the DOM. Fetch an HTML snippet over AJAX and inject it into the DOM.

There'a whole lot of question on StackOverflow but nothing conclusive. I've found a few examples that use this approach

```
    const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(response.data)
    document.querySelector("#temp").appendChild(fragment)
```

While this works, it doesn't seem to be supported on older browsers and there doesn't seem to be a Polyfill.

I've found this article that suggests some alternatives but none of them are encapsulated into a reusable bit of code. https://ghinda.net/article/script-tags/

Is there an alternative DOM method or NPM library that I could potentially use to do this? I'm afraid that home-rolling a mechanism will lead to a myriad of alternate issues.

Comment: The most cross-browser way I know of is to extract the script tag and pass it to `eval()`. Note that there is zero difference in security risk between passing your script to `eval()` and inserting it as `script` tag in the document: in both cases you are evaling a string as javascript

Comment: I was thinking the same. Just wondering if there's a lib for this as many might have hit this issue.

Comment: Generally no. Instead people would just not use this method. The most recommended way is not to do it at all. The ready-to-use alternatives are to rewrite your template as React or Angular. That's what Facebook did - they invented React to do it and shared React with the world so everyone can do it too

Comment: Thx @slebetman. I wish I could do that. Unfortunately, I'm mopping up a legacy codebase. It works similarly to how ads work, you have placeholders into which content/banners are fetched and executed dynamically. There's a few scripts that are often loaded - carousels, sliders, etc.